# How can I overload abstract constructor in derived class

Tags: java, php

I have an abstract constructor and a derived class like follows:

```
abstract ab {
  ab();
}

class dc {
  dc();
}
```

I want to execute first the constructor of the derived class and then execute the constructor of the abstract class

Please give me an example.

Comment: Can't be done in Java.  Super class constructor *must* be invoked first.  Game over.

Comment: ehm ... which language? Which class extends which? ...

Comment: how is dc a derived class of ab in this example?? dc seems to be an entirely new class that is derived from nothing (but base object class)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use composition over inheritance.

```
Class SuperClass {
  AbstractClass abstractClass;

  public SuperClass() {
    doStuff();

    abstractClass = new ConcreteClass();
  }
}
```

This links gives more explanation http://tiedyedfreaks.org/eric/CompositionVsInheritance.html

Answer (score 5):

In java **Parent class** constructor is called before **Child's constructor**  and this call is made by Child constructor only.

**Answer is No .** This is not possible.